# How does order of index affect performance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I am wondering how does order of index affect performance (ASC, DESC) ? If it affects, why ? And which order should I choose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1337/building-sql-server-indexes-in-ascending-vs-descending-order/) article someone looked at the performance of an index and the ordering of the data in the index.

> **Summary**
>
> As we have shown creating an index in ascending or descending order does not make a big difference when there is only one column, but when there is a need to sort data in two different directions one column in ascending order and the other column in descending order the way the index is created does make a big difference.